# expose Togglebutton ischecked property

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 usercontrols, UC1 & UC2: 
UC1: have 3 togglebuttons , Button1, Button2, Button3
UC2: have canvas with UI elements. etc: ellipse1

I want to hide ellipse1 when Button1.ischecked == true

I exposed the checked status of togglebutton, but i read false all the time.

UC1:

```
public ButtonLayout()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        public bool IsToggleChecked
        {
            get { return (bool)Button1.IsChecked; }

        }
```

UC2:

```
ButtonLayout buttons = new ButtonLayout();
            if (buttons.IsToggleChecked == true)
            {
                elip1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
```

Please let me know where i am going wrong

Comment: As is, your example would be false because the default value of IsChecked is false, and since you seem to read the value right after constructing your ButtonLayout class, there is no time for it to be anything else.  I would think that your code is more complex than this, so perhaps you should edit the question to better reflect your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expose the `Checked` and `UnChecked` events for your `ToggleButtons` and subscribe to them from UC2. There the eventhandler can hide/show the ellipse.

Note: you could aggregate the two events from the `ToggleButton` into one `ToggleStateChanged` event that you handle from UC2.

```
    public event Action<bool> ToggleStateChanged;

    public ButtonLayout()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ToggleButton1.Checked += (sender, e) => ToggleStateChanged?.Invoke(true);
        ToggleButton1.UnChecked += (sender, e) => ToggleStateChanged?.Invoke(false);
    }
```

and UC2:

```
    ButtonLayout buttons = new ButtonLayout();
    buttons.ToggleStateChanged += SetVisibility;
```

with

```
    private void SetVisibility(bool isChecked)
    {
         elip1.Visibility = isChecked? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visisble;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Johan! thank you for your reply. Can you please elaborate your answer. do i need to make dependency ?

Comment: PS: if you really want to develop serious applications in WPF, later on you may want to look into the MVVM architecture pattern...